# Clone directory structure from an http server without downloading actual files

Tags: http, curl, download, wget

I want to obtain a local copy of a publicly available directory hierarchy (actual site in question is http://download.tizen.org). I don't want to get any actual files because they are large. However I would like to know which files reside in each of the directories (just the files' names).

I have a Mac and a Debian box. Windows solutions are also OK.

Solution without an actual local copy which allows to quickly browse and *search* the hierarchy for patterns also will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can either clone everything with [wget -r](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100570/getting-files-all-at-once-from-a-web-page-using-curl) or you need to parse the files you get with curl..

There is no simple way to do this task only with curl..

Comment: I don't mind using wget or whatever else. However I don't see how to avoid downloading the files.